# Data Structure to find number of integers in some range in constant time

Tags: data-structures

Say I have an array of n integers
I need to create a data structure that can allow me to find the number of integers in some range [a,b] in the array.

I was thinking some form of counting sort?

Answer (score 1):

Any efficient searching algorithm will require sorted input data. Then you can easily retrieve the bounding indexes in O(log(n)) time.

Constant time retrieval can probably only be achieved by generating a lookup table. If you know the bounds for a and b, that should not be too hard. You'll be trading time efficiency for memory space, though. Guess this is what you mean by "counting sort".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, counting part of the counting sort algorithm works for you. Which is essentially what
jackrabbit has said.

Answer (score 0):

Quick sort the array.  Binary search to find a.  Iterate over the array from a until you find b.

I'm guessing you want to do this without sorting, because otherwise the question is too simple.

If the data is unsorted, you cannot know the final value until you read it, so you would have to iterate over the whole array every time.